# Do Skyrim perks apply to companions as well?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Very simply put, do perks in Skyrim apply to companions as well? For instance, upgraded Archery skills, stealth backstab bonuses, etc.

Or do they just apply to the main player? It could have a big impact on strategic playing of Skyrim.

I was fairly sure I'd find this already asked, but it appears to either be a new question or else the search is failing me.

Comment: I searched and could not find the answer here either. However, there is no reason to believe perks would affect followers. Much like increasing your health at level up does not increase the health of every follower. They don't even gain levels with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, your followers do not get your skills/perks, they have their own set. This allows you to have mage or fighter companions regardless of your own skill set.